# Cuál es la diferencia entre Element y Token en los métodos de la clase StringTokenizer de JAVA?

Tags: java

La clase `StringTokenizer` posee métodos que diferencian los *Element* con los *Token*, por ejemplo `hasMoreElements` y `hasMoreTokens`
Sus definiciones en [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) no son del todo claras respecto de qué es realmente un *Element* y qué es un *Token* dentro de la clase.
Alquien conoce estas definiciones?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que la documentación es clara: `hasMoreElements` y `hasMoreTokens` hace lo mismo, y `hasMoreElements` existe para que `StringTokenizer` pueda implementar la interfaz `Enumeration`:

Esta es la [definición del método](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#hasMoreElements()):

> **`hasMoreElements`**
>
> Returns the same value as the hasMoreTokens method. It exists so that
>   this class can implement the Enumeration interface.
>
> Specified by: hasMoreElements in interface Enumeration
>
> Returns:
>
> true if there are more tokens; false otherwise.
>
> See Also: Enumeration, hasMoreTokens()

Traducido diría esto (las negritas son mías):

> Devuelve **el mismo valor que el método `hasMoreTokens`**. Existe para
>   que esta clase **pueda implementar la interfaz [`Enumeration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html)**.

Si observas la explicación de `Returns`, podrás entender que un `Element` no sería otra cosa que un `Token` (las negritas son mías):

> Retorna
>
> `true` si hay más **tokens**; `false` de lo contrario.

Por tanto, puedes usar cualquiera de los dos métodos, pues hacen lo mismo.